# Structure with vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, structure

I have some problems with sending structure to function:
[image: errors]

Here is my main.cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "vehicles.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "tools.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>


using MAP_GRID = vector<vector<string>>;
using namespace std;

void print_terrain(MAP_GRID);
void set_position(MAP_GRID &, int, int, position &, string);
void random_position(MAP_GRID &, int, string);
MAP_GRID create_terrain();

MAP_GRID MAP = create_terrain();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    tanks t34(12, 0.5, 21,6);
    srand(time(NULL));

    set_position(MAP, 5, 5, player,"[x]");
//[...]
}
```

Here is another file, with definition of this function:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define MIN_SIZE 6
#define MAX_SIZE 15

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using MAP_GRID = vector<vector<string>>;
int global_size;

struct position{
    vector<int> x;
    vector<int> y;
};

void set_position(MAP_GRID &MAP, int x, int y, position &pos, string object)
{
    if (x <= MAP.size() || y <= MAP.size())
        if (MAP[x][y] != "[ ]")
            std::cout << "\nPosition is occupied" << std::endl;
        else
        {
            MAP[x][y] = object;
            pos.x.push_back(x);
            pos.y.push_back(y);
        }

    else
        std::cout << "\Choose correct position" << std::endl;
}
```

This structure have to hold coordinate of some point (numbers of these points depends of object).

Comment: The first 2 errors are simple: there is no variable called `player`, and there is no type called `position`. The third error, I believe, is a result of the first one. There does not seem to be any problem here related to the vectors.

Comment: I declared structure position outside function - it isn' global?

Comment: @Kulis: You still have to declare it before use.

Comment: @Kulis Ah, now I see the problem. Your first file does not #include the second one, and therefore does not see the declaration of `struct position`.

Comment: I copied definition of structure to main.cpp (from terrain.cpp), but still I have problem with last line https://imgur.com/kcTP0i1

Comment: @Kulis This is the same problem. You can't just copy the definition, you need to #include the file where that definition actually is.

Comment: @Tal I created new .h file writed there definition of this structure and I added header file to these two .cpp file, but these coused many errors: https://imgur.com/GeWiTEh https://imgur.com/NjQgY3k

Comment: @Kulis Your header file needs `using std::vector;`, I think this should fix most of the compilation errors.

Comment: It's better, but is any posible to put this structure to class https://imgur.com/sW38e2O? Now gives me many errors. I declared the function as void set_position(MAP_GRID &, int, int, vehicles::position, string);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63509/discussion-between-kulis-and-tal).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing at all to do with vectors (as you'd have discovered, had you constructed a [minimal testcase](http://sscce.org) during your many days of painstakingly debugging this problem).

You have to at least *declare* identifiers in every translation unit you want to use them in, before you use them.

You have not done that, so the compilation of main.cpp will fail because, indeed, it has no idea what `position` is supposed to be. `player` is, likewise, a complete mystery.

Typically we define *types* in "header files", making for easy inclusion of these definitions across multiple translation units. In this case, you can at least get away with a forward declaration of `position`.